# How can I add the Rockstar Games Launcher version of GTA V into GOG Galaxy 2?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, gog, gog-galaxy-2.0

I have the Rockstar Games Launcher version of Grand Theft Auto V. How can I add it into GOG Galaxy 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a Rockstar Games Launcher/Social Club community integration available on the Settings of GOG Galaxy. It correctly detects the Grand Theft Auto V copy from the Rockstar Games Launcher.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Integrations between GOG Galaxy 2.0 and 3rd party clients are nearly all community driven. You can search for community integrations for a specific 3rd party client in the settings menu. I'm working from home right now, so I can't easily check the client, but I think I already managed to add my own Rockstar games launcher integration to my own install. I might be mistaken on that though.